# Hibernate save issue - Save works fine on Local machine but fails on Server

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am facing an issue while saving an entity to database on `RDS`. The issue is beyond my understaning as the ***`save` works fine when i execute the application on my machine. i.e. from Intellij (don't know if mentioning Intellij is worthy or not).***

Here is the entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "spr_material")

public class SprMaterial {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
public Timestamp createdAt;

@Column(name = "service_name")
public String serviceName;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at")
public Timestamp updatedAt;

@Column(name = "isDeleted")
private Boolean isDeleted;

@Transient
private int serialNo;


@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "dep_id", nullable = true)
private Department department;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "item_code", nullable = true)
private StockRawMaterial rawMaterial;

// removing get/set methods

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: "+this.id+ " Created At: "+this.createdAt+ " Service Name: "+this.serviceName+ " Deleted: "+this.isDeleted
            + " Department Id: "+this.department.getDepId()+ " Raw Material Id: "+this.rawMaterial.getRawMaterialId();
    }
}
```

Here is the chunk of code that saves the data to database

In `Controller` class

```
@PostMapping("/spr/save")
public String sprMaterial_save(@ModelAttribute("sprForm") SprForm sprForm, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    SprMaterial sprMaterial = new SprMaterial();
    sprMaterial.setId(sprMaterialService.getMaxId());
    sprMaterial.setServiceName(sprForm.getServiceName());
    sprMaterial.setRawMaterial(rawMaterialService.findById(sprForm.getItemCode()));
    sprMaterial.setDepartment(departmentService.findByDeptId(sprForm.getDepartmentId()));
    //sprMaterial.setDeleted(false);
    logger.info("TESTING");
    SprMaterial saved = sprMaterialService.save(sprMaterial);
    if(saved == null){
        System.out.println("Could not saved object");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Saved Successful");
    }
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("addedSuccess", "success");
    return "redirect:/spr/accounts";
}
```

In service class

```
@Override
    public SprMaterial save(SprMaterial sprMaterial) {
        logger.info("SAVING SPR MATERIAL: "+sprMaterial.toString());
        SprMaterial rm = sprRepository.save(sprMaterial);
        logger.info("after saving: "+rm.toString());
        return rm;
    }
```

UPDATE: I am using jpa default `save` method. Here is the repository class.

```
public interface SprRepository extends JpaRepository<SprMaterial, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT spr.* FROM spr_material spr JOIN department d ON d.dep_id = spr.dep_id WHERE d.name LIKE ?1 AND spr.isDeleted = FALSE ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
            countQuery = "SELECT spr.* FROM spr_material spr JOIN department d ON d.dep_id = spr.dep_id WHERE d.name LIKE ?1 AND spr.isDeleted = FALSE ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<SprMaterial> findSprMaterialById(String name, Pageable pageable);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE spr_material spr SET spr.`isDeleted` = 1 WHERE spr.`id` = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteSprMaterial(Integer sprMaterialId);

    SprMaterial findById(Integer sprMaterialId);

    @Query(value = "SELECT MAX(spr.`id`) + 1 FROM spr_material spr",nativeQuery = true)
    Integer getMaxId();

    @Query(value = "select * from spr_material spr where spr.`dep_id`=?1",nativeQuery = true)
    SprMaterial findByDepId(Integer deptId);

}
```

On tomcat `catalina.out` i get the following logs and get a page with `504` error

```
14-Jun-2019 11:58:45.363 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-34] com.qsa.account.web.SprMaterialController.sprMaterial_save TESTING
14-Jun-2019 11:58:45.374 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-34] com.qsa.account.service.sprMaterial.SprMaterialServiceImpl.save SAVING SPR MATERIAL: ID: 2 Created At: null Service Name: Vilcor Disc Repair and Maintenance Deleted: false Department Id: 7 Raw Material Id: 5350
Hibernate: select sprmateria0_.id as id1_53_0_, sprmateria0_.created_at as created_2_53_0_, sprmateria0_.dep_id as dep_id6_53_0_, sprmateria0_.isDeleted as isDelete3_53_0_, sprmateria0_.item_code as item_cod7_53_0_, sprmateria0_.service_name as service_4_53_0_, sprmateria0_.updated_at as updated_5_53_0_ from spr_material sprmateria0_ where sprmateria0_.id=?
11:58:45,384 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [2]
11:58:45,413  WARN PageNotFound:215 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Comment: your controller isn't accepting a POST request

Comment: @David it does, you can see in the logs as well

Comment: Please show the code from the Repository, too

Comment: @Turo I have added the reposity interface as well. Btw I am using the jpa's `save` method.

Comment: Can you show the code of your controller?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yeah, i have added the controller's `post` method

Comment: and how do you call this method?

Comment: I submit a form with three fields from front end from browser. My application is hosted on ec2 instace and db is on RDS.

Comment: Ok, I have resolved the issue by removing `nullable = false, updatable = false` from `createdAt` field. But I still don't know why the code was working fine on my local machine and was failing with out any logs on `Amazon ec2` instance with `RDS`. I had to add `try/catch` block around the `save` function in controller that show me the error. `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value`.
I am leaving the question open if someone can explain the scenario.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace . It's always important to include the stacktrace in a question if you get an exception!